# How do I repopulate multiple textareas with their specific user input (saved as an array in localStorage) on refresh?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm building a scheduling web app, and it shows a table of rows with time of day, a text area, and a save button side by side for each hour of the day. The user can type their info into the textarea next to a given time, click the button, and it will save their input to localStorage. On refresh, the localStorage still shows the saved user input when I console.log it, but it won't repopulate the textareas with it. I want their user input to still show up in those textareas when they refresh the page, but something about how I'm using localStorage.getItem doesn't seem to be working. I'd love some help, and thank you!

(Sorry in advance that the images are posting as links, it won't let me embed them)

[Here's an example of the HTML I have for each row of the table, which includes the textarea.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4w0h.png)

[This is my current JS for adding the user input to localStorage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12iND.png)

[And this is all I've got for my getItem function so far, which is what I need help fixing!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhSGJ.png)

--

UPDATE: This is the final code that fixed my issues!

```
// save button was clicked
for (var i = 0; i < saveBtns.length; i++){
saveBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // define event text array
    var events = [];
    for (var i = 9; i <= 17; i++) {
        events[i] = document.getElementById(i).value;
    }

    //save events to localStorage
    localStorage.setItem("events", JSON.stringify(events));
    console.log(localStorage);
})};

// load saved user input on refresh
var loadEvents = function() {
    var events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("events"));

    // populate the textareas
    for (var hour in events) {
        if (events[hour]) // check if value is not null
        document.getElementById(hour).value = events[hour];
    }
}

loadEvents();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the time in 24 hour format (i.e 0-24 where 17:00 = (17-12)PM = 5PM). This will let you store 9AM to 5PM with numbers 9-17 as index, which is chronological & a perfect ascending order as opposed to 9-12 then resetting to 1-5PM.

Store the values at indexes which represent the hour of the day:

```js
var events = [];
// 9AM to 5PM
for(var i=9; i<=17; i++) {
    events[i] = document.getElementById(i).value;
}
```

**Make sure each textarea has an ID of the number in 24 hour format (9-17 in this case).**

Now, you need to set the `value` property of the textareas after getting the item from localStorage.

```js
var loadEvents = function() {
    var events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("events"));

    // Populate the textareas
    for (var hour in events) {
        if(events[hour]) // Check if value is not null
            document.getElementById(hour).value = events[hour];
    }
}
```

If you want it to be repopulated on page load:

```js
document.addEventListener('load', loadEvents);
```

Keep in mind the `load` event will only fire if your script loads *before* the page loads. If your script loads after the page loads, you can simply call the function instead:

```js
loadEvents();
```

Comment: The schedule actually starts at 9am, so the 9am textarea is the first textarea on the page. It only spans 9am to 5pm, which is why the values are in that order. Should I still be creating the events array differently?

Comment: Also thank you for that note about how to include my code! This was my first question ever, so I wasn't sure how best to format it.

Comment: I just tried reformatting the events array like that, and it messed up the order of my localStorage. Now it's trying to order them 1-12, instead of chronologically 9-5 the way they're laid out on the page, and it gave me null values for every number that isn't listed as an hour on the page (i.e 0, 6, 7, and 8).

Comment: @mellimel Only a for..in loop will work with the format because all other keys are null. A for..in iterates through each key that exists: 9..12 & 1..5. And yes, the order of the array is changed with this method, I didn't know that was a requirement.

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it chronological using 24 hour numbers. You can do it with 12 hour numbers but it will be less elegant.

Comment: I do have the time stored in 24hr format (each textarea has an id from 9 to 17), but I'm still getting nine null values in the array before it logs my actual textarea input starting with 9am. I put it in a for...in loop like you suggested, so I'm not sure what I'm still doing wrong. Sorry I just started teaching myself JS a few weeks ago...

Comment: I just updated my original question post with the code I currently have, and aside from the null values in localStorage, it still won't repopulate the textareas with the events array values when the page reloads.

Comment: @mellimel My bad, `JSON.parse` actually sets all keys which don't have a value to `null`, which is why you were getting those values. As for it not getting repopulated, your script might be running *after* the page load event fires.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect these changes

Answer (score 0):

If you have the above requirements, you should not refresh your screen, but only store your data.

If you really need to refresh the screen, you can consider taking out the data and re-assigning the value to the component after the screen is refreshed.

Comment: I do need to have the ability to refresh (it's a requirement of the assignment), so how do I reassign the values?

Comment: There are many ways to assign values ​​to elements, this is the way in JS  document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = 'your_value';

Comment: Where would that go in my code? I tried adding it to my loadEvents function, but since I already defined my textareas as variables at the top of my code because I use them elsewhere as well, it's sort of like writing nine.value = 'nine.value', and that's having no effect.

Comment: You only need to add code to the outermost layer of the js file, because the page refresh will re-execute the entire js file again.

Comment: I tried that, but nothing is happening. They're all still there in localStorage but not showing in the textareas.

Comment: Please provide your code, otherwise I can't understand your situation.

Comment: There are screenshots of my code linked in my main question